# In Visual Studio 2017 is there a way to enable the Source Control dialog from a Tab?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When working in Visual Studio 2017, it would be handy to have access to the Source Control dialog to "Undo Checkout" when you right click on the tab for an open document.  We frequently work with complex solutions where files we work on concurrently reside in many different folders.  Finding and opening the folder for an opened file is annoying when the task I need to perform is an "Undo Checkout".

Reviewing these preferences, I don't see anything that would enable this type of feature from opened tabs.

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows
Tools > Options > Source Control
```

Is what I'm requesting an available feature, and if so how can I enable it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way of altering the tabs in VS2017 without maybe a plug-in extension.

However, you can right-click on the editor window (where the code is displayed) and in the displayed context menu is a Source Control submenu which will offer the option to "Undo" if changes are pending.

Also, You can add the "Team Explorer" window to one of the sidebars or as a tab in an existing pop-out. I like to have Properties, Solution Explorer, and Team Explorer tabbed together and displayed to the side of the editor work area.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  I didn't know right-clicking on the editor window would make that menu available.  It's probably been a feature for a long time.  That's a time saver.